# Appending strings to value of attribute in XML tag

Tags: xml, vbscript

I need to replace value of attribute `ciphers` in XML tag `<Connector>`

```
<Connector sslEnabledProtocols="SSLv2Hello,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
  ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
/>
```

The problem is that, as you can see, the string is very long, and I replace it with equally long one.
I'm using VBScript to do the replacing (I'm replacing also another, shorter, string), but I have a problem because of the length of the string. Here is the code I have:

```vb
Dim objXMLDoc
Dim objXMLElement
Dim objXMLNodeList

Dim oXML
Set oXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

oXML.load(dir)

If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
  Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "//Service/Connector[@port=""3170""]"
  Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = oXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
  If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "oops"
  Else
    ndFnd.getAttributeNode("ciphers").value = WScript.Arguments(2) & WScript.Arguments(3) & WScript.Arguments(4) & WScript.Arguments(5)
    oXML.save(dir)
  End If
End If
```

I already had to split that string into four variables that I pass at the command line. Is there a way to append to the value of the attribute?

Right now I get

> Subscript out of range

Comment: How are you running the script? I suspect that you provide less than 6 parameters while the script expects at least 6.

Comment: I run it from Custom Action in MSI installer - WiseScript to be exact. When I run it standalone it works fine.

Comment: I don't have experience with WiseScript, but you need to check what arguments are passed to the script.